# Override property

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a base class I'm creating a property with `property()` function:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Person(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name, telephone):
        self.name = name
        self.telephone = telephone

    def get_name(self) -> str:
        return self.__name

    def set_name(self, value: str):
        self.__name = value

    name = property(fget=get_name, fset=set_name)
```

And in the derived class I need to override the `set_name` method, that is, `Person.name.fset` should point to a modified version of the method. I tried this but it did not work:

```
class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, telephone, email):
        super().__init__(name, telephone)
        self.email = email

    def set_name(self, value):
        super().set_name('override')

    Person.name.fset = set_name
```

Is there any way to override property in python?

Comment: You have to override the *whole* property. So something like `name = property(fget=Person.name.fget, fset=set_name)`

Comment: As an aside, your `Person.name` property is totally pointless. Why are you using double-underscores for `__name`? Just use `.name` in your `__init__` and be done with it. There's no need for a property if all it does is literally get and set an attribute. That defeats *the whole purpose of property objects to begin with*

Comment: Your answer is correct. Put it as answer so it will be useful to someone else.

Comment: This is just an example of overriding properties.